# Is it possible to specialize on some (not all) class template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Is it possible to specialize on some (not all) class template parameters?

For example:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class TC
{
public:
 void Foo();
};

template <typename T, typename U>
void TC<T, U>::Foo()
{

}

template <???, typename U>
void TC<int, U>::Foo()
{
  //Want this defined for all U but only when T is int.
}

int main(int argv, char * args [])
{
 TC<int, char> tc;
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally you can specialize just some template parameters of a class template, this is called "partial specialization". When doing this you create a new, specialized version of the template that "overrides" the general version.

In your case it seems that you only want to specialize a part of the template, the `Foo()` method, but this is not possible. You have to specialize the whole `TC` class:

```
// specialization for T=int
template <typename U>
class TC<int, U> {
public:
  void Foo();
};

// implementation of Foo() for the specialized template
template <typename U>
void TC<int, U>::Foo()
{
  //Want this defined for all U but only when T is int.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For classes, yes. For functions, no and yes.

Partial template specialization is fine for classes, but for global functions it's a little more tricky.

For classes, you simply omit the specialized arguments from the template parameter list and include it in the class definition:

```
// General template class for a vector
template <class T, int N>
struct Vector
{
  T e[N];
};

// Specialization for N=3
template <class T> // omit the N
struct Vector<T, 3> // and include it here
{
  T e[3];

  static Vector<T, 3> cross(const Vector<T, 3>& a, const Vector<T, 3>& b)
  {
    return Vector<T, 3>( a.e[1] * b.e[2] - a.e[2] * b.e[1],
                         a.e[2] * b.e[0] - a.e[0] * b.e[2],
                         a.e[0] * b.e[1] - a.e[1] * b.e[0] );

  }
};
```

For global functions, you can't do that. You can either define a function that is fully general, or fully specialized -- partial specialization of functions is disallowed.

However, you can partially specialize a function by creating it as a proxy for a static function of a partially specialized class.

e.g.

```
template <class A, class B>
void foo(A a, B b)
{
  foo_impl::fun(a, b);
}

template <class A, class B>
struct foo_impl
{
  static void fun(A a, B b)
  {
    // real implementation here
  }
};
```

You can then specialize `foo_impl` in any way you want, and that will be reflected in `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish only to specialize part of the class, you need the original class to provide hooks. It's generally describes as `Traits` or `Policies` depending on the implementation.

A `Traits` class is a class that references some properties, and sometimes methods, for a given type and is not passed explicitly. An example in the STL is `std::iterator_traits<It>`.

A `Policy` class is a class passed as a template parameter that is used to implement a number of functionality. An example in the STL is `std::less<int>` in `std::set<int, std::less<int> >`.

In general, the use of a `Policy` class is explicit while the use of a `Traits` is implicit... and thus I prefer the former to the latter.

If your class does not use these hooks, then report to `sth` answer on partial specialization and note that the *partial* means that some parameters are still template, and not that you only wish to specialize a part of the class, for indeed you have to redefine everything.